# Firebase Database Batching

Tags: javascript, caching, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to know how smart is Firebase database, whether it batches together multiple database requests if I call them synchronously?

For example, if below I make two identical requests, will it send to the backend only the last one, or both?

```
firebase.database().ref('test').set(1);
firebase.database().ref('test').set(2);
```

Also, if I read synchronously multiple times the same location, will it send the request to the backend multiple times, or will it understand that the same location is read?

```
firebase.database().ref('test').once('value', snap => {});
firebase.database().ref('test').once('value', snap => {});
```

Also, what is the overhead of listening for some path? In terms of memory and bandwidth. What is the maximum number of listeners per user I can use to not impact user's experience?

```
firebase.database().ref('...').on('value', snap => {});
```

Answer (score 0):

*firebaser here*

There is no way these writes can be merged together, because you might have validation rules (which are only enforced on the server) that only accept the second write once the first one had been Each write request will be sent to the database. So in your first snippet, two write operations will be sent.

Firebase will only retrieve the data for each location it is listening to once. So if you keep an active listener, a second listener on that location will get the existing data from the cache.

But in your scenario you don't keep an active listener, because you're using `once()`. When you use `once()`, the listener is removed as soon as the result of the read is received by the client.

When you execute the two lines right after each other, they will still likely get the same read. But if these lines are further apart, the first listener will have already been removed and thus the data has been removed from the cache already.